# Android WebView 'Browswer is out of date or some of its features are disabled'

Tags: android, webview, android-websettings

I am trying to load a Website in my app using WebView. Here's my webView set

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            getWindow().setTitle(title); 
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");
```

The webView is loading the website but it says

> Your browser is out of date or some of it's features may be disabled

Can anyone help me with the settings of webView?

Comment: Why do you use setuseragentstring?

Comment: Cause I'm new in android :) @Steven. 
My Problem was solved. This is the link I've followed. 
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/12/23/important-steps-to-improve-android-webview-performance/

Comment: Okey good to know your problem is solved but I never have seen `setUserAgentString`